# finding multiple lines patterns and stop after first occurence

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, find

I have got plenty of files in different location including */synth/debug/* in their path pattern, all files have got *.list extension. Files look like:

```
MODULE XYZ
SIGNED_A 0
WIDTH 12
SIGNED_B 1
(...)

MODULE XXX
SIGNED_A 1
WIDTH 12
SIGNED_B 0
(...and so on...)
```

I need to find first file with MODULE XXX (the same for XYZ and so on) and SIGNED*1 pattern in the first 3 line after MODULE XXX and stop searching. SIGNED word appears always in 1-3 line after MODULE.

I've got something like that:

```
find . -name *.list -path "*/synth/debug/*" -type f -exec grep -FHI "MODULE XXX" -A 3 {} \; | grep "SIGNED 1" -A 3 | head -1
```

but got:

```
find: ‘grep’ terminated by signal 13
```

after first (correct) occurence and the command still searching and parsing files wasting the time.

Comment: What would your intended output look like? Pretty sure this is a `sed` problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk

```
find . -name *.list -path "*/synth/debug/*" -type f -exec awk '/MODULE XXX/{xxx=1;next}xxx{xxx+=1}/SIGNED.*1/&&xxx<=4{print FILENAME; exit}xxx>4{nextfile;}ENDFILE{xxx=0}' {} +
```

Output is name of the first file matching your conditions

Remove `xxx>4{nextfile;}` if a file contains multiple MODULE XXX blocks

To process every module in 1 command :

```
find . -name *.list -path "*/synth/debug/*" -type f -exec awk '/MODULE/{current=$2; line=1; next}current in results{next;}{line+=1}/SIGNED.*1/&&line<=4{results[current]=FILENAME}END{for(module in results){print module, results[module]}}' {} +
```

Output : module name + first file matching conditions :

```
ABC file2.txt
XXX file1.txt
XYZ file1.txt
```

Comment: It is possible to stop searching for module XXX in other files when pattern for this module already occured once? Now I've got:

    XXX file1.txt
    (...)
    XXX file2.txt

Comment: @J.Doe which command did you use ? this should not be possible, both commands prevent this behavior (1st command use `exit` to stop searching other files, 2nd command use associative array and it is not possible to have two different values for one key + has `current in results{next;}` to stop searching modules that have been found already)

Comment: I'm using second one. I think problem is that, that file1.txt and file2.txt are located in different directories:

XXX /path1/file1.txt
XXX /path2/file2.txt

Comment: @J.Doe : do you use `find ... -exec awk ... {} \;` instead of `find ... -exec awk ... {} +` ? First one runs one awk command per file, second one runs awk once for all.

Comment: I used find ... -exec awk ... {} +
and got one result for certain path (even in situation when there is more files that match pattern in the path, which is correct), however when pattern is present in file in another location - I got second result for MODULE XXX

XXX /path1/file1.txt
XXX /path2/file2.txt

Comment: Do you execute the command more than once ? Did you include the command in a for loop or something ? @J.Doe

Comment: If not, I have to say that I don't know why. You can still post process the result like this :  `find . -name *.list -path "*/synth/debug/*" -type f -exec awk '/MODULE/{current=$2; line=1; next}current in results{next;}{line+=1}/SIGNED.*1/&&line<=4{results[current]=FILENAME}END{for(module in results){print module, results[module]}}' {} + | sort -u -k1,1`

Comment: maybe problem is that in "MODULE XXX" line I've got some extra characters afterwards:

MODULE XXX \smth1
MODULE XXX \smth2
and so on. For me it doesn't matter what is after MODULE XXX, all that lines should be treat as same.

Comment: should not unless there is no space between XXX and \smth.

Comment: but space is always present, thank you for your help :)